# JQuery function, supposed to only go off on a certain class, keeps firing even though class was removed from tag

Tags: jquery, html

Just starting out with Jquery pretty much, I have a function that will append an input box below another one. I want this to only happen with the very last one, so I set the class on the new one that is created and removed the tag from the previous one. However, the function only works with the tag that originally had the class on it. Here is the code:

```
<html>
<body>
     <div id="inputs">
        <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Enter text"><br>
        <input type="text" class="appending-input" placeholder="Enter text"><br>
     </div>

     <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){  
        $(".appending-input").keydown( function() {
          $(".appending-input").attr("class", "input");
          $("#inputs").append('<input type="text" class="appending-input" placeholder="Enter text"><br>')
        });
      });
     </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Is it not possible to change the class on tags so the function won't happen. Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want input types gets only append when last input type is filled use .on for binding of function to dynamic created input type.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
 <div id="inputs">
    <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Enter text"><br>
    <input type="text" class="appending-input" placeholder="Enter text"><br>
 </div>

 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){  
   $(document).on('keydown', '.appending-input', function() {
      $(".appending-input").attr("class", "input");
      $("#inputs").append('<input type="text" class="appending-input" placeholder="Enter text"><br>')
    });
  });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because, although the event no longer has the class, the event handler is still bound to it.

If you only want the event to fire on the element once, you can use `one()` instead:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".appending-input").one('keydown', function() {
    $(this).prop("class", "input");
    $("#inputs").append('<input type="text" class="appending-input" placeholder="Enter text"><br>')
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inputs">
  <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Enter text"><br />
  <input type="text" class="appending-input" placeholder="Enter text"><br />
</div>
```